# Memory alignment in C

Tags: c, memory, alignment

Here is a snippet:

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct s1
{
    char a;
    long b;
};
#pragma pack()

#pragma pack(2)
struct s2
{
    char c;
    struct s1 st1;
};
#pragma pack()


#pragma pack(2)
struct s3
{
    char a;
    long b;
};
#pragma pack()

#pragma pack(4)
struct s4
{
    char c;
    struct s3 st3;
};
#pragma pack()
```

I though sizeof(s4) should be 10 or 12. But it turns out to be 8.
I am using Visual C++ 6.0. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: The reason why I thought sizeof(s4) is 10 based on:|c|Padding|Padding|Padding|a|Padding|b|b|b|b|. But the actual layout is |c|Padding|a|Padding|b|b|b|b|.

Comment: On your system, the `sizeof(long)` is 4. Thats why `sizeof(s3)` is 6 and `sizeof(s4)` is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#pragma pack(2)
struct s3
{
    char a;
    long b;
};
#pragma pack()
```

So the packing alignment of `s3` is 2, and its size is 1 (alignment 1) + 1 (padding) + 4 (alignment 2) = 6.

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct s4
{
    char c;
    struct s3 st3;
};
#pragma pack()
```

The packing alignment of `s4` is 4, and its size is 1 (alignment 1) + 1 (padding) + 6 (alignment 2) = 8.

Note that `#pragma pack` doesn't "extra-align" anything with looser alignment requirements. It only reduces alignment, i.e. controls "packing" alignment.

Comment: As the alignment of s4 is 4, It should be 1 + 3(padding) + 6 = 10. or 1 + 3(padding) + 6 + 2(padding) = 12.

Comment: @user1758245: No. All it means is that each *member* of it will require alignment *no greater than* 4. It doesn't mean that each member *will* have alignment requirement 4. Notice, after all, it's called `pack` and not `align` for a reason -- precisely because it controls packing, not alignment. `__declspec(align(#))` might be what you need though.

Comment: user1758245: Why 3(padding)? The alignment of s3 is 2, so it only needs 1(padding) after `char c`.

Comment: I finally understand "pack" and "align". Thank you. And thank all those who have answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for `#pragma pack(n)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) says  that "The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller".  However I think this is incorrect; the docs should say that the alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or *the alignment requirement of the member*, whichever is smaller.

The alignment requirement of `struct s3` is 2 (due to the `#pragma pack(2)` in effect when it was declared). So it still gets an alignment of 2 even in the struct that has a `#pragma pack(4)` in effect. So the layout of `struct s4` looks like:

```
 char c;
 char padding;      // for alignment of the `struct s3`
 char s3.a;
 char s3.padding;   // for alignment
 long s3.b;
```

Total size == 8.

Answer (score 0):

In `s3`, `char` (1) + `long` (4) = 5 -> 6 (packed)

In `s4`, `char` (1) + `struct s3` (6) = 7 -> 8 (packed)

I'm not actually sure how `#pragma pack` works, but this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This verifies what Michael Burr said:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct s3
{
    long b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct s4
{
    char c;
    struct s3 st3;
};

int main() {
    printf("%lu, %lu\n", sizeof(s3), sizeof(s4));
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 4, 6